# What to do when user says they meant different question after you have answered

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I posted an answer for a user’s question and he indicated he was going to try my solution. After some time he had not indicated whether or not it worked. I commented to ask if it worked or did he encounter a problem. His reply was that he was actually looking for the answer to a different question which he did not post. He also did not edit his original question. Is there any action I can or should take?

Comment: I personally go for some combination of {downvote, close as unclear, post comment linking to [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270345)}.

Comment: Leave a comment to the OP saying to open a new question with their actual question, and vote/flag to close the first Q as off-topic -- "seemingly went away on its own". I would ask the OP to delete their stale question, but I'm not sure if your existing answer would prevent that (or if your answer would need to be up-voted for that to be the case).

Comment: @JeffSchaller can't delete with a question with multiple answers (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/270345)

Comment: Related:  [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/195817) and [OP edited question substantially after answer(s) were posted](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9514/150988).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My opinion for this situation:

1. Leave a comment on the question to the effect of "please open a new/separate Question with your actual question".
2. Flag (or, if you have the [Close Privilege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), Vote to Close) the question as "Off-topic: problem went away on its own".

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Jeff](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4736/80216#4737)
that the OP should be encouraged to ask a new question.

If the OP edited the question in such a way that your answer is invalidated,
see [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/195817)
and [OP edited question substantially after answer(s) were posted](https://meta.superuser.com/q/9514/150988),
as cited in [the comment by Scott](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4736/80216#comment8363_4736).

But, if the OP left the question alone,
and only *commented* that they were looking for something else,
or if they edited the question to *add* qualifying details,
and you have posted a correct answer to the (original) question,
it’s not necessarily appropriate
to flag/close the question as “problem went away”. 
See [What to do when a user changes their question
using details provided by an answer?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4770/80216),
which discusses [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420572/80216),
which does not appear to have gone away on its own. 
(The “Unclear” and “Too broad” options remain.)