# What to do when a user changes their question using details provided by an answer?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420572/how-to-copy-the-old-disk-data) started out as "How do I copy data from an old `LVM` installation"

I answered it by giving the user an appropriate solution, but it turned out that his `LVM` installation was actually corrupt. So in chat the user asked me if I could help him recover his data, as I did not know how to do that, I asked the user to create a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420577/how-do-i-recover-a-lost-lvm-volume-group-not-found-by-vgscan-and-lvmdiskscan) with the appropriate details to get an answer for that specific question.

I asked the user to create a new question because I thought the answer I gave for the original question might help other people in the future that were looking for a solution to `mount` and copy data from older `LVM` installations, and also to make a more clean question asking for a specific answer.

Should I have asked him to edit his question to request for help regarding the recovery of the partition or creating a new question was the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @G-Man I am not sure if it is an *exact* dupe - the user changes the question *using the details provided by an answer*. I think it is the behavior of the help vampires - he could ask an infinite long question list, but too lazy to press the "Ask Question" button twice. It is a significantly different problem from the dupes (which is not really a problem). This category is imho more like the "multiple questions packed into one" problem.